# Spring initialization failure related with CXF 2.4.10

Tags: java, web-services, spring, apache, cxf

We have a working system with following technologies

```
<spring-version>3.0.1.RELEASE</spring-version>
<quartz-version>1.5.2</quartz-version>
<axi2-version>1.5.4</axi2-version>
<cxf.version>2.2.12</cxf.version>
```

But after I tried to upgrade our dependencies some binding problems occured and I couldn't find any answer on web so I'm looking for help.

I upgraded spring and quartz successfully, but when I tired to upgrade cxf it became a nightmare.

Now we are running on Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE with Quartz 1.8.6 but we can not go any higher than cxf 2.3.11,

When I tired to use cxf 2.7.2 first I had some conflicts about XmlSchema (method not found exception), I overcome it by excluding old version from axis2 dependencies (XmlSchema 1.4.3) and imported latest version xmlschema-core 2.0.3 and problem solved.

But I started to get the following exception, this is happening immediatly after going upper than cxf 2.3.11.

```
    Oca 24, 2013 5:36:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4323)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4780)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:763)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:557)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1124)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1047)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1390)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:293)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:996)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:988)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at com.googlecode.t7mp.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:52)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:357)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:246)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:525)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
        ... 65 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:338)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.createBindingInfo(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:181)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpointInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:258)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:143)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:207)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:442)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:329)
        ... 74 more

    Oca 24, 2013 5:36:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    Oca 24, 2013 5:36:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/mpp] startup failed due to previous errors
    Oca 24, 2013 5:36:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    Oca 24, 2013 5:36:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
    SEVERE: The web application [/mpp] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    Oca 24, 2013 5:36:38 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
    SEVERE: The web application [/mpp] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I have already read the migration documantation but coudnt find any answer regarding to my problem.

This is what my shortnened pom.xml looks like

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <cxf.version>2.6.0</cxf.version>
        <aspectjrt-version>1.6.2</aspectjrt-version>
        <aspectjweaver-version>1.5.0</aspectjweaver-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- CXF Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is my webservice interface

```
    @WebService(name="UserWSImplService", targetNamespace = "http://user.services.ws.fourplay.com.tr/")
    public interface UserWSIF
```

This is my webservice implementation

```
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "tr.com.fourplay.ws.services.user.UserWSIF")
    public class UserWSImpl implements UserWSIF
```

This is my config xml

```
    <bean id="userDBImpl" class="tr.com.fourplay.db.services.user.UserDBImpl" />
    <bean id="userSrv" class="tr.com.fourplay.ws.services.user.UserWSImpl" >
        <property name="dbImpl" ref="userDBImpl" />
    </bean>

    <jaxws:endpoint id="userService" implementor="#userSrv" address="/userService" >
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

This is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

        <display-name>Mobile Service Platform</display-name>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:application-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
            <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: In you config xml are you importing the resources cxf.xml, cxf-servlet.xml and cxf-extension-soap.xml?

Comment: Yes Manuel, here are they 

        <!-- Apache CXF imports -->
        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
 
I'm not importing cxf-extension-soap.xml here is a small info from cxf offical site. 

Changes in CXF 2.4.x
The above is applicable for CXF versions 2.3.x and older. Starting in CXF 2.4.0, the extensions are loaded internally by CXF automatically and you do not need to import all the cxf-extension-*.xml file. You only need to import classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Spring-context-not-loading-when-upgrading-from-2-2-9-to-2-4-1-version-td4518167.html

The problem is related with  configuration.

```
Hi,

Cxf bus refactor a lot since cxf 2.4.0.
In your spring configuration
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
is unnecessary
and you need change
<bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl" />
to something like
<cxf:bus/>

Freeman
```

Comment: Can you please provide complete WEB.xml and/or cxf-servlet.xml ?

Comment: I am facing similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224520/apche-cxf-3-with-spring-4-invocation-of-init-method-failed-nested-exception-is      can you plz help