# Apche CXF 3 with Spring 4. Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I trying to create simple webservice using apache CXF and Spring. Versions are

```
<cxf.version>3.1.7</cxf.version>
<spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Tutorial I am referring is [here](http://www.baeldung.com/apache-cxf-with-spring)

my `cxf-servlet.xml` file looks like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <jaxws:endpoint id="sayHelloEndpoint"
        implementor="com.kaushik.winnersoft.serverside.impl.HelloWorldImpl" address="http://localhost:8080/services/sayHelloService" />
</beans>
```

I get following error

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sayHelloEndpoint': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
May 28, 2017 12:06:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sayHelloEndpoint': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
```

Comment: Can you share your code for implementation? You need to check Where is this REFLECTION field init method is looking for.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade It looks like version compatibility issue. I change both CXF and Spring to previous version and it worked. So I need to know latest compatible versions.